# Blazor @Onchanged / @bind for List item

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, blazor

I want to do a **DbUpdate** for a **List item** every time a checkbox is ticked.
My List is the property but it does not fire the SET when a @bind in the foreach is changed. I also cannot use @Bind on the foreach and use an @Onchanged at the same time.
How could i achieve my goal and what is the best blazor practice?

**Foreach:**
First checkbox handles the method but the passed object is not changed by the "Checked"
The second checkbox changes the bool of the object but i can't use @Onchange in combination with @Bind

```
@foreach (var configuration in dashboardConfigurations)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@configuration.Customer.Name</td>
                    <td>@configuration.Customer.Vat</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" @onchange="@(async () => await SaveConfiguration(configuration))" checked="@configuration.UploadPurchaseInvoices"/></td> 
                    <td><input type="checkbox" @bind="configuration.UploadSalesInvoices" /></td>
                    <td><button @onclick="@(()=> TestMethod(1))">Disable Customer</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
```

**For:**
Hoped that a change of the textbox would call the SET of my parameter List but is does nothing...

```
@for(int i = 0; i < DashboardConfigurations.Count; i++){
                <tr>
                    <td>@DashboardConfigurations[i].Customer.Name</td>
                    <td>@DashboardConfigurations[i].Customer.Vat</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" @bind="DashboardConfigurations[i].UploadPurchaseInvoices"/></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" @bind="DashboardConfigurations[i].UploadSalesInvoices" /></td>
                    <td><button @onclick="@(()=> TestMethod(1))">Disable Customer</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
```

**Code:**

```
@code { 

    private List<CustomerDashboardConfiguration> dashboardConfigurations;
    [Parameter]
    public List<CustomerDashboardConfiguration> DashboardConfigurations
    {
        get { return dashboardConfigurations; }
        set { dashboardConfigurations = value; }
    }

    internal async Task SaveConfiguration(CustomerDashboardConfiguration customerDashboardConfiguration)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saving object");
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This works and is exactly what i am trying to achieve but it is pretty ugly in my foreach:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" @onchange="@(async e =>{configuration.UploadPurchaseInvoices = (bool)e.Value;  await SaveConfiguration(configuration);})" checked="@configuration.UploadPurchaseInvoices"/></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian has answered the first part of your question.

> This works and is exactly what i am trying to achieve but it is pretty ugly in my foreach.

```cs
<td><input type="checkbox" @onchange="@(async e =>{configuration.UploadPurchaseInvoices = (bool)e.Value;  await SaveConfiguration(configuration);})" checked="@configuration.UploadPurchaseInvoices"/></td>
```

Sure is!  Move the anonymous method into the code section and just call the method.

```
<td>
   <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      @onchange="(e) => CheckboxChanged(configuration, e)" 
      checked="@configuration.UploadPurchaseInvoices"
   />
</td>

@code {
//....
async Task CheckboxChanged(DashboardConfiguration configuration, ChangeEventArgs e) 
   {
      configuration.UploadPurchaseInvoices = (bool)e.Value;
      await SaveConfiguration(configuration);
   }
}
```

> Wish there was a way to use the bound object so the (bool)e.Value isn't needed anymore but this works to!

There is.  See the code below.  But there is a problem on event timing that the code illustrates.

```cs
@page "/counter"

<div>
    <input type="checkbox" @bind-value=Checked @oninput=Changed /> CheckBox
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
    Checked : @Checked
</div>

<div class="alert alert-secondary m-2">
    Message : @message
</div>

@code {
    private bool Checked { get; set; }
    private string message = string.Empty;

    private void Changed( ChangeEventArgs e )
    {
        message = $"Clicked at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}. Sumitted Value is {e.Value?.ToString()}  Checked Property was {Checked}.";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Wish there was a way to use the bound object so the (bool)e.Value isn't needed anymore but this works to! Thanks

Comment: @Joben - see my updated answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Might use it in the future. For now i will keep using my old way instead of putting the e.value in my method because i have to reuse the method for different props